Does the Terran Empire come back? When?
So... I haven't watched (most of) DS9. Apparently at some point (according to some things I've read here), the Terran Empire is overthrown and replaced by the Klingon-Cardassian Alliance (in 2295?). I believe this information is revealed in ~2370?
Now, Star Trek Online is not exactly canon, however they usually don't ignore canon, and the Empire's appearance in STO is quite recent, certainly years after DS9 concluded, so the authors would know about any canon from DS9.
Is there some event that results in the Terran Empire being "reborn"? Or what explanation is given for why it is alive and well from some time before 2348? (Note: the backstory of the Emperor as of the beginning of the STO arc makes it clear that the Empire was around since at least his birth, which was 2348.) Or is STO just ignoring this part of canon?

Maybe someone who's played the game can offer more detail, but it looks like the history of its rebirth is covered in the sections "Terran Rebellion" and "Second Terran Empire" on the STO wiki page

@Hypnosifl, ah, I must have missed most of that. I'll have to replay the relevant mission, though, as I'm not sure the bits around the Emperor's birth, ~2348-2349, mesh with humans being supposedly enslaved at that point... Plus, (mirror) Picard is apparently captain of the (mirror) Enterprise during roughly the same years as TNG.
